# Ploting Date in Java and SQL

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, date

Hello I have some problems when ploting a Short Date column("FECHA") from an access database.This is my code when ploting:

```
 ResultSet rs2=statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CITAS WHERE PACIENTE Like '"+user+"' ");
 if(rs2.next()){
 toClient1.println("<p>Su cita es: "+rs2.getString("FECHA")+" "+rs2.getString("HORA")+"</p>");
```

When I do this I get this as a result:

> 2017-05-22 00:00:00.000000 9

How do I get rid of all those 0s?

Comment: what you expect to get?

Comment: did you try with getDate instead ?

Comment: 2017-05-22 only?

Comment: Please edit the title of your Question to describe the core issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to format date in java

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
df.format(rs.getDate("FECHA"));
```

Comment: did you mean `yyyy-MM-dd` :)

Comment: df will be a date object or a String?

Comment: df is SimpleDateFormat instance

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should check whether your Access database has got a datatype for both date (fecha) and time (hora) so it donesn’t have to be two separate fields in the table.

Next, you should check whether you have or can get a sufficiently new JDBC driver that it can use the newer `java.time` classes. If so, use `rs2.getObject()` to get such an object from your result set. I haven’t got the experience to tell you exactly which type to expect, but once you find out, it should be easier to work with than both the strings you have and the `Date` object that Nitin Prabhu suggests in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44087314/5772882).

Finally, if all goes well, use a `DateTimeFormatter` or two to format the object/s from the database into the format your users want. You may for example use [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE) to obtain `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
"2017-05-22 00:00:00.000000 9".substring( 0 , 10 )
```

…or…

```
myResultSet.getObject( "FECHA" , LocalDate.class )
```

## `String::substring`

Extract the characters you want. Call [`String::substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-). Annoyingly, the arguments for that method are zero-based index numbers.

```
String output = "2017-05-22 00:00:00.000000 9".substring( 0 , 10 ) ;
```

> 2017-05-22

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/vc3Mtw).

## Use objects, not strings

When exchanging data with a database, you should be using objects rather than mere strings. For date-time values, use date-time objects instantiated from date-time classes.

You do not document here the nature of your table. If `FECHA` is a date-only type, and your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) supports [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221), then you can use the java.time types directly. See [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44087588/642706)

- [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-)
- [`ResultSet::getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-)

Example:

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( "FECHA" , LocalDate.class ) ;
```